# soap request format for search.asmx

Tags: search, apple-ios

I am trying to access the search.asmx query operation from the iPhone. I am getting a response code of 400 .

Right now the format i am sending to service is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<Query xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
<queryXml><query><term field="Keywords">dolphin</term></query> </queryXml>
</Query>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can someone point out where i am going wrong please?